# Protecting my Google identity in case my Android device gets stolen?

Tags: security, 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

My devices are all linked to my main Google account. This is encouraged, almost required, by Android, for example to make my Google Play apps available everywhere. However, it requires me to store my main Google password on the device, which provides access to a ton of sensitive data: all email, Drive documents, Google Wallet.

What can I do to protect myself in case one of my devices gets stolen?

The devices I currently have are Google Nexus 5 and Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1

Comment: Minor correction: AFAIK the password itself is not stored on the device, it's just an AUTH token. So you could simply visit your Google account's website, and revoke permission for your devices. Or (if it works) use the mentioned device manager to locate/lock/wipe it.

Comment: @Izzy: thanks. Can you tell me where exactly I can revoke that permission?  I logged into my account page, looked under Security, and it doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: As to my understanding: on https://security.google.com/settings/security?pli=1 scroll to the very end *(Connected applications and sites)*, click the link next to it *(Review Permissions)*. On the next page, you can "Revoke Access" to *Android Login Service*. While each device seems to have its own entry here, which one belongs to which device seems to be a lottery unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google now has a device manager as part of Google services where you can do a remote wipe:

https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager

At least put a pin lock on your device so that it will be harder to access.

Don't enable Developer Options / keep adb on all the time.

Comment: Thanks. Insofar as password-locks on the device itself go, that pin code is the most I can do, right?  There's no option for a more secure lock, or encryption of the entire drive?

Comment: I'm not sure when it became available but you can encrypt your device under Settings->Security->Encrypt. I've got that option on both a Samsung Note with 4.0.4 and a Nexus 7.